# Is that possible to setup CouchDB enabled website URL mapping without Apache as reverse proxy?

Tags: couchdb, iriscouch

Actually I'm running this with Apache as reverse proxy in front of CouchDB:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.com
        ServerAlias www.abc.com

        ProxyPass /abc http://localhost:5984/abc
        ProxyPassReverse /abc http://localhost:5984/abc

        ProxyPass /_session http://localhost:5984/_session
        ProxyPassReverse /_session http://localhost:5984/_session

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:5984/abc/_design/tt/_rewrite/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5984/abc/_design/tt/_rewrite/

</VirtualHost>
```

Is that possible to setup `[vhosts]` inside CouchDB itself to run it without Apache reverse proxy at front?

Comment: Yes it's possible, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yep. Have played with `[vhosts]` but without success. Could anyone gimme `[vhosts]` alternative for my `ProxyPass` config? Just any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[vhosts](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/http.html#config-vhosts) work with the `Host` HTTP header for routing primarilly.

Combine that with [rewrite rules](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/rewrites.html?highlight=rewrite) (they are part of design documents) to accomplish what you are seeking to do.